# RQuantLib, Hoadley and Bloomberg YAS: fixed rate bond pricing differences?

Tags: fixed-income, r, pricing, bond, bloomberg

I'm trying to price a fixed rate bond one year from now on.

The bond is the PEUGOT 7 ⅜ 03/06/18, whose ISIN code is FR0011439975. I'm using such a specific example because in this way everyone can try to reproduce results.

I am using these instruments:

- Bloomberg `YAS` function
- `RQuantLib` package `FixedRateBondPriceByYield()` function
- Hoadley Excel add-in `HoadleyBond()` function

and getting different results.

Then there must be something wrong with me, because fixed rate bond pricing is an easy task.

Bond's features (`RQuantLib` / Hoadley fields name):

- faceAmount / principal $= 100$
- effectiveDate / Valuation_date = 10 May 2014
- maturityDate / Maturity = 6 March 2018
- rates / Coupon_rate $= 0.07375$
- period / Coupon_freq $= 1$ (Annual)
- yield / Term_struc $= 0.06535$ (flat curve due to pricing with YTM)
- redemption $= 100$

Other arguments, such as settlement days, calendar rules and so on, can be ignored because I don't need such an accuracy.

Results:

- Bloomberg `YAS` function clean price $= 102.72$
- `RQuantLib` package `FixedRateBondPriceByYield()` function clean price $= 96.67$
- Hoadley Excel add-in `HoadleyBond()` function clean price $= 103.31$

Where's my mistake? What am I not taking into consideration?

Comment: You probably won't get any answers unless you post complete source code and data on dropbox or something.  Even then, it's a roll of the dice.

Comment: Hi Brian B. I've included all data which are needed to price that bond, I do not understand what else could make my question more comprehensible. I could attach `R` code but in fact it is sufficient one to copy each field value in `FixedRateBondPriceByYield()` to get the same result... unless I've made some mistakes, that is quite likely according to the difference with Bloomberg `YAS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in RQuantLib you need to set the evaluation date using setEvaluationDate()
This is the date used by all QuantLib valuation functions in your case 10 May 2014.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:
effectiveDate / Valuation_date = 10 May 2014

Good that you included the ISIN, which states that the effective date (as contrasted with the issue date) was a few days after 03 May 2013.

Comment: Then, if I understand my mistake, you're telling me I switched `effectiveDate` field with the `issueDate` one: if I wanted to calculate the price of this bond with `RQuantLib` on 10 May 2014 I would have to set `issueDate <- '2014-05-10'` and `effectiveDate <- '2013-05-03'`. Correct?

Comment: rather, make issueDate <-  effectiveDate <- as.Date('2013-05-03')

Comment: effectiveDate means the date the bond begins to accrue interest, the date it functionally goes 'live'; issueDate is the date investors first get the chance to buy-in. For your purposes just set them equal to each other.

Comment: But if `issueDate <- effectiveDate <- as.Date('2013-05-03')` how can I evaluate this bond on 10 May 2014? Doesn't `issueDate <- effectiveDate <- as.Date('2013-05-03')` make the pricing on 03 May 2013 instead of 10 May 2014?

Comment: set settlement days to 365. effectiveDate has a very precise meaning in this context and simply can't be used interchangeably as a valuation date. regards...

Answer (score 2):

Let's approximate the time to maturity to be 3 years and 10 months. Assume that coupon is paid on March 6 each year. Let face value $F=100$ and coupon $c=0.07375F$. Let the discount factor be $d(0,T)=e^{−r T}$ where $r=0.06535$. The price of the bond is
$$ce^{−10/12 \bullet r}+ce^{−22/12 \bullet r}+ce^{−34/12 \bullet r}+(F+c)e^{−46/12 \bullet r}=103.24 \; .$$
Since the discount rate $r$ < coupon rate, I don't see how the price of the bond can be less than 100.